# Is the word "exile" a comparable noun for the word "expatriate"?

Tags: meaning

Cambridge dictionary provides the following definition for the noun expatriate:

> Someone who does not live in their own country

Cambridge dictionary also states that the word "exile" is a comparable noun (for the word expatriate), defined as:

> The condition of someone being sent or kept away from their own country, village, etc., especially for political reasons

So, in what way are these words comparable, **other** than the fact that one does not live in his or her country anymore?

Comment: Do you mean **exile**? Also note that there is a ***verb*** *exile* as well as a  ***noun*** *expatriate*. Why would you wish to mix the two, when you can use the noun that is the specifically intended equivalent of the verb? Using a synonym will never be as precise as the original thing.

Comment: Being an expatriate is voluntary - the expatriate may return to his home country, etc., at any time. Being an exile is usually mandatory, you have been expelled from your country or escaped from your country and would suffer if you returned.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JasonBassford.